# Deleting rows where any of several columns is a duplicate

Tags: r, unique, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with an ID column, and several attribute columns. I would like to drop all the rows in my dataframe where any one of the attribute columns (or multiple) is identical to any other attribute column. In other words, I only want to keep the rows where each attribute is a unique value within the row.

For example, using this code:

```
    example = data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), attr1 = seq(1,4), attr2 =     c(2, 3, 3, 1), attr3 = c(1, 2, 3, 3))
```

which results in this dataframe:

```
id  attr1   attr2   attr3
a     1     2       1
b     2     3       2
c     3     3       3
d     4     1       3
```

I would want to drop all of the rows but the last one, with ID "d".

I've looked for ways to do this, but this particular problem (unique within rows) I'm not sure how to solve -- if they were columns it would be easy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So it looks like you are just grabbing every row which doesn't have a d as the value for ID? This isn't really what I'm looking for -- my actual data has ~1MM rows and I don't know in advance which ID values are going to have duplicates in the other columns. Sorry If I've misunderstood.

Comment: `example[apply(example[-1],1, function(x) length(unique(x))==3),]`

Comment: Oh -- I am deleting all rows BUT the last row, sorry for the confusion. I want to drop row 1 and 2 because attr1 and attr3 are identical, row 3 because all attr columns are identical, and not drop row 4 at all

Comment: @Frank I didn't read it properly.  I was reading it from the last line :-)

Comment: Ah got it -- that's a great solution, I need to get better at using apply row-wise, thank you!

Comment: Could you test if this is fast enough?

Comment: It's not bad! ~20 seconds for 1MM rows and 5 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `anyDuplicated`

```
 example[!apply(example[-1], 1, anyDuplicated),]
 #  id attr1 attr2 attr3
 #4  d     4     1     3
```

Or

```
 example[apply(example[-1],1, function(x) length(unique(x))==3),]
```

Or using `regex`

```
 example[!nzchar(sub('^(?:([0-9])(?!.*\\1))*$', '',
              do.call(paste0, example[-1]), perl=TRUE)),]
```

#### Benchmarks

```
example1 <- example[rep(1:nrow(example),1e6),]
system.time(example1[!apply(example1[-1], 1, anyDuplicated),])
#   user  system elapsed 
# 32.953   0.222  33.239 

 system.time(example1[!apply(example1[-1], 1,
       function(x) length(unique(x))==3),])
#   user  system elapsed 
# 35.409   0.185  35.659 

system.time(example1[!nzchar(sub('^(?:([0-9])(?!.*\\1))*$', 
           '', do.call(paste0, example1[-1]), perl=TRUE)),])
# user  system elapsed 
# 10.033   0.020  10.069
```